# Validar si existe registro con el mismo id en formulario y arrojar un alert confirm de ser asi

Tags: javascript, php, json, mysqli, alertify

Buen dia,

La verdad estoy volviéndome un poco loco porque sinceramente no se como hacerlo e investigando no hallo con una solución.
Lo que necesito o requiero es que yo envió un formulario pero al momento de registrarlo deseo que se haga una validación y que al momento de hacer esa validación si existe el id (cedula,rut) me muestre un alert confirm diciéndome que si realmente deseo agregar este registro.
En este caso estoy enviando el formulario por javascript a un ajax y de ahí se realiza el insert y eso, utilizo alertify para las alerta. Adjunto el código del formulario, del script y del php.

***HTML***

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST" id="frmnuevoU">
                    <div>
                        <label>Cedula</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="Cedula" name="Cedula" required>
                    
                    </div>
                    <label>Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="Nombres" name="Nombres" readonly>
                    
                    <label>Fecha de Ingreso</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" id="FIngreso" name="FIngreso" value="1980-01-01" readonly>
                    <label for="file">Datos adjuntos</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control input-sm" id="file" name="file" accept=".pdf" required/><br><br>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="btnAgregarnuevo" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn">Agregar</button>
                </form>
```

Tambien cabe recalcar que el formulario asi como esta funciona perfectamente, registra los datos y todo. Esto lo recibo por medio de javascript y utilizo el metodo DataForm debido a que tengo input tipo file y fue la unica manera con la que pude trabajar con ajax.

***JS***

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#frmnuevo").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'procesos/agregar.php',
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                $('#frmnuevo').css("opacity", ".5");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.status){
                    $('#frmnuevo')[0].reset();
                    $('#tablaDatatable').load('tabla.php');
                    alertify.success("Se agrego con exito :D");
                    return;
                            
        }else{        
            alertify.error(data.message);
            $('#frmnuevo')[0].reset();
                    $('#tablaDatatable').load('tabla.php');
            }
                       $('#frmnuevo').css("opacity","");
                       $(".submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
            
        }
        });
    });
```

Y ya por ultimo aunque no se si sea importante el php que se ejecuta en el ajax.

***PHP***

```
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    $uploadedFile=$target_file;
    $Cedula=$_POST['Cedula'];
    
    //insert form data in the database
    $insert = mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO referencias(`F_Presentacion`, 
    `F_Respuesta`, 
    `adjuntos`,
    `F_Ingreso` ) 
    VALUES ('$FPresentacion',$FI)");
    
    //Si todo está bien retornamos true en el status
    
    } } 

    $response['message'] = "success"; 
    $response['status'] = true; 
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit(); //Detenemos el código

}
```

Resumí bastante el código del php, debido a que no lo vi tan necesario pero como explicaba anteriormente funciona muy bien, con el no tengo ningún tipo de problema ni nada.
Ahora teniendo en cuenta lo anterior como seria la forma mas sencilla o facil o mejor dicho como podria realizar lo que deseo realizar?

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es un **SELECT** primero, donde busques esa cédula, si la encuentra entre los registros con un **if** controlarías la respuesta, si la encuentra ejecutas el alert, si no (**else**) ejecutas el Insert.

Comment: @AntonioGalicia pero eso iria dentro del php, correcto?

Comment: Hay varias formas, pero eso te serviria.